# Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 wireless network adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, atheros

I just purchased a Lenovo Yoga 3, 14". It comes with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4 wireless network adapter. I have not been successful getting this wifi to work. I have tried some suggestions for Yogas but they, apparently use a different adapter. I have also tried ndiswrapper without any luck. I downloaded a windows driver which installed fine and indicated that it found matching hardware, but still no wifi.

If I cannot get it working soon, I'll have to send the machine back. Life without Ubuntu is not to be considered. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my Qualcomm Atheros 61x4 running on a ubuntu 15.04 clean install. Actually not for the Lenovo model but for an Acer Aspire VN7 Nitro 791G These are the steps I accomplished:

- install kernel sources: apt-get install linux-headers-(uname -r)
- downloaded the athk master sources from kvalo: git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath.git
- downloaded the backports tree: "git clone
  git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/backports/backports.git"
- built the new backport tree according to the instructions found on linux-wireless: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/backports
- downloaded the firmware from sumdog and copied it to /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/ :

(Sorry I am not allowed to post more than two links)

"wget github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware/raw/5faf5bb7c7413f9bbde54cca6fff58e/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin"

and

"wget github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware/raw/5faf5bb7c7413f9bbde54cca6fff58e/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin"

- created athk10 config file as described in this post before:
  sudo echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf
- copied firmware-4.bin to firmware-5.bin as dmesg claimed about not finding firmware-5.bin

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
The Intel 3160NGW card is the one to get for the Yoga 3 11 and Yoga 3 14. I did the replacement and can confirm it works. If you do this, **make sure you get a card with FCC ID PD93160NGU**, other IDs will **not** be recognized by the BIOS.

Original post:
I've got a Yoga 3 11, which has the same Atheros card (QCA61x4). I've been tracking the driver issue closely, and it looks bleak. There is some movement for a QCA6174 driver, but I'm sort of sure it won't work for the QCA61x4 (different PCI listings -- 003e for 6174, 0041 for 61x4). I can imagine *eventually* we'll have linux kernel support, but it will be a while.

I like the computer a lot, so I'm keeping it. In the meantime, I'm using USB wifi, and I ordered a replacement intel wifi card (3160NGW). The yoga has a picky BIOS, and the 3160 is the one to get for our model based on reading Lenovo's published [compliance documents](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_yoga_3_1170_rn_us_ca.pdf). If you decide to replace the wifi card, make sure you get one with a matching FCC ID. For the 14 model, I would verify that the wifi also uses the M.2 connection. Good luck!

Comment: Drat! That's bad news. I also like the format of the machine, but I need wifi. Just to clarify, did you put in the 3160NGW? Can you confirm that it works? Can you clarify the need for a matching FCC ID? In shopping around the FCC ID is rarely listed. Non matched the FCC ID on my machine. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't try using one without a matching FCC ID. But I did manage to install the 3160NGW yesterday, and it worked perfectly. The FCC code was not listed in my purchase on ebay where I got the card, but I was able to discern that the card had an FCC ID matching the one in the regulatory notice from the picture of the card that was posted.

Comment: WakkaDojo would you mind sharing your purchased FCC ID + photo, and post a link to the ebay seller where you bought your card? I've seen both P93160NG and P93160NGW cards, while the compliance document seems to require P93160NGU. (Just got a Lenovo Yoga 3-14 myself) Sorry this is not an answer per se, just registered and was not allowed to comment - only post an answer. (Weird policy)

Comment: The links I posted contain the answers to everything you asked. The FCC ID must be PD93160NGU, with the U, as is stated in the compliance document above. This is the one I bought: [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/GENUINE-LENOVO-IDEAPAD-FLEX-2-14-20404-TOUCH-14-LAPTOP-WIRELESS-WIFI-BT3160NGW-/161624861762?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2047675.l2557&nma=true&si=1dhG5fV9xSwxtYZ2nrytBLhVoik%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc). It's a little hard to find but they're out there.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine Lenovo yoga 3 11:

```
uname -r
3.19.0-15

lspci -nn
...Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 20)
```

I fixed the problem like this.

But I booted from a USB stick with Ubuntu 15.04 so you will have to slightly adept the steps below for a full installation.

1. Downloaded the driver from
   http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~adamlee/lp1383184/ath10k-dkms_1.1_all.deb
2. Copy it to the stick. (I did it from Windows )
3. Boot into Ubuntu and cd to the directory where you copied the file. (Hint: start looking for the files under /media/cdrom)
4. `sudo dpkg -i ./ath10k-dkms_1.1_all.deb`
5. Reboot

Hope this can fix it also for you!